# Using getCurrentPosition and returning false but form still submits

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get some coordinates using geolocation in Javascript but for some reason I return a false value and the form still submits. As you will see in the code, the function `saveData()` returns false if some validations fail and true if all validations pass. I am checking the value of the `check` variable and even if it is false it still submits the form.

```
$("#save").click(function(){
    var check = true;
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
        $('#lat-location-end').attr('value', position.coords.latitude);
        $('#lon-location-end').attr('value',position.coords.longitude);
        check = saveData();
        return check;
    }, function(){
        $('#lat-location-end').attr('value', '0.00000000');
        $('#lon-location-end').attr('value', '0.00000000');
        check = saveData();
        return check;
    });
    return check;
});

function saveData(){
    var odleave = $('#odometer-leave').val();
    var odarrival = $('#odometer-arrival').val();
    var miles = $('#mil').data('mile');

    if (odarrival < odleave){
        alert("Odometer: Arrival must not be less than Odometer: Leave");
        return false;
    }

    if (odleave != miles){
        if (odleave > miles){
            var mile_diff = odleave - miles;
            if (mile_diff > 25){
                if (!confirm("Your leaving mileage exceeds by " + mile_diff + " miles from your last mileage. Do you want to continue?"))
                    return false;
            }
        } else {
            if(!confirm("Mileage entered is less than your last mileage. Are you using a new car?"))
                return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm assuming that `#save` is a `submit` button? If so, you should hook to the `submit` event of the form instead.

Comment: I did this

`<form method="post" id="q_form" action="/save" onsubmit="saveData()" role="save" class="container">`

I think I might be doing something wrong. I need to get the coords first then execute the code in `saveData()`